# Obtener tipo de una propiedad de entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, reflexión

Buenas,

Necesitaría obtener en tiempo de ejecución, el tipo de dato de la propiedad correspondiente:

```
foreach(string  unaPropiedad in listColumnNames)
{
   clsEntidad.getype().getproperty(unaPropiedad);
   PropertyInfo prop= prop.propertyType;
   Type tipo= Type.GetTypeCode(prop);
 }
    switch (tipo)
    {
        case TypeCode.Byte:
       //-------

}
```

Cuando consulto el tipo en el `switch` siempre recibo el tipo base `Object` no el tipo de la propiedad en cuestión.
¿Alguna idea o alternativa para enfocar esto?

Gracias.

Comment: Hola!, podrías aclarar de donde sale `unaProiedad`? es parte del foreach?

Comment: Editado! Gracias Alan

Comment: que relacion tiene esto con entity framework o asp.net mvc? de dodne sale listColumnNames ?

Comment: Listcolumns es un listado de nombres de columnas, que son las propiedades que tiene mi entidad en una aplicación MVC.La idea es obtener el tipo de cada propiedad iterada

Answer (score 2):

El siguiente codigo me funciona correctamente

```
public class clsEntidad
{
    public byte prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
}


private void TestReflection()
{
    string[] listColumnNames = new string[] { "prop1", "prop2" };

    clsEntidad entity = new clsEntidad();

    foreach (string unaPropiedad in listColumnNames)
    {
        var prop = entity.GetType().GetProperty(unaPropiedad);
        //PropertyInfo prop = prop.PropertyType;
        TypeCode typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(prop.PropertyType);
        switch (typeCode)
        {
            case TypeCode.Byte:
                //codigo
                break;

        }
    }

}
```

veras que del Type obtienes el TypeCode

Answer (score 2):

En tu caso lo resolvería de esta manera:

Esta línea `clsEntidad.getype().getproperty(unaPropiedad);` deberías reemplazarla por:

```
var prop = typeof(clsEntidad).GetProperty(unaPropiedad);
```

Estás Utilizando el enumerado TypeCode para identificarlos en el switch correctamente solo que asignas un valor `int` a una variable del tipo `Type` en la línea: `Type tipo = Type.GetTypeCode(prop);`

Suponiendo una clase:

```
    public class clsEntidad
    {
        public int Propiead1 { get; set; }
        public decimal Propiedad2 { get; set; }
    }
```

el código quedaría así:

```
        string[] listColumnNames = new string[] { "Propiead1", "Propiedad2" };

        foreach (string unaPropiedad in listColumnNames)
        {
            var prop = typeof(clsEntidad).GetProperty(unaPropiedad);
            TypeCode tipo = Type.GetTypeCode(prop.PropertyType);

            switch (tipo)
            {
                case TypeCode.Int32:
                    Console.WriteLine("Propiedad del Tipo: {0}",tipo);
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Decimal:
                    Console.WriteLine("Propiedad del Tipo: {0} ",tipo);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

---

Para obtener las propiedades de una clase y sus tipos puedes hacerlo de esta manera (es un proyecto de consola por una cuestión de rapidez pero espero te sirva) :

```
class Program
{
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public short MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    public decimal MyProperty3 { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var t in typeof(Program).GetProperties())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ", t.PropertyType.FullName);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

y la salida sería:

> System.Int32
>
> System.Int16
>
> System.Decimal

Answer (score 0):

Exacto, muy parecido es el codigo que utilizo pero lo que me extraña es que obtengo al hacer el switch  tipo **object** en todos las  propiedades iteradas, no los tipos int32,datetime etc...

Comment: deberias agregar un comentario, no una respuesta

Comment: analizaste el codigo de ejemplo que implemente? compralo con tu codigo y valida donde puede estar el problema. Recuerda que el GetTypeCode() devuelve un TypeCode no un Type

Comment: Revisando el codigo el problema esta en que los tipos recuperados para propiedades de tipo (DateTime o Int32) los devuelve como Object..sera porque no son tipos primitivos.¿Existe alguna alternativa para tratar estos casos?

Comment: @Kram_ fijate en la segunda parte de mi respuesta, ahi tenes otra forma de tratarlo, no es elegante pero sirve.